# How to parent tr checked if child tr is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Info**: I am try to make a nested table. The table have `parent && child rows`.

***The feature***

- I want to make if user click on `parent tr>input:checkbox` the all `child tr>input:checkbox` checked.
  I want to know if any `parent-tr` `child-tr` checkbox is checked then parent-tr also checked.
- Parent `tr` automatically checked If user checked child input:checkbox checked one by one manually even if i checked only one. if under the parent child unchecked parents also unchecked.

```js
function childRowCheck() {
    const childRow = $("tr#child-tr input:checked")
    childRow.each(function (i, item) {
        let tbody = $(this).parents("tbody");
        tbody.children("tr#parent-tr").eq(i).find(":checkbox").attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    })
}
childRowCheck();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <!-- BEGIN::Subject loop -->
    <tr id="parent-tr" class="parent-tr" data-id="2">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" value="2" id="id_subject">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END::Subject loop -->

    <!-- BEGIN::Tickers loop -->
    <tr id="child-tr" class="child-tr" data-ticker-id="6" data-subject-id="2">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tikcer" id="id_ticker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="child-tr" class="child-tr" data-ticker-id="7" data-subject-id="2">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tikcer" id="id_ticker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="child-tr" class="child-tr" data-ticker-id="8" data-subject-id="2">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tikcer" id="id_ticker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END::Tickers loop -->
    <!-- BEGIN::Subject loop -->
    <tr id="parent-tr" class="parent-tr" data-id="3">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" value="3" id="id_subject">
        </td>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END::Subject loop -->

    <!-- BEGIN::Tickers loop -->
    <tr id="child-tr" class="child-tr" data-ticker-id="9" data-subject-id="3">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tikcer" id="id_ticker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="child-tr" class="child-tr" data-ticker-id="10" data-subject-id="3">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tikcer" id="id_ticker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="child-tr" class="child-tr" data-ticker-id="11" data-subject-id="3">
        <td class="action">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tikcer" id="id_ticker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END::Tickers loop -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: id attributes need to be **unique** across a page. You are using `parent-tr` and `child-tr` over and over again.

Comment: if i make it unique then how can i access each id's

Comment: That's what `class` is for. Using the same id value more than once will make your JavaScript code not work.

Comment: Is it possible to change the HTML? If you can use a hierarchical HTML structure, such as `ul`/`li`, then this becomes trivial to achieve.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no this is not possible in my working i want to use table instead of `ul/li`

Answer (score 0):

You have much better control of your application, if you control the data and not the UI:

- create a data structure that best suits the relation(s) between the elements
- create a template that can be re-used to populate the DOM

The main benefit of the solution below is that you **always have a correct state** that you can use (e.g. submit); also the shape of the data does not change: the input & output of your process look the same.

I put one more level of depth (so parent->child->grandchild) to show that it works quite nice with **n** levels hierarchy.

```js
const data = [{
    id: "parent-tr-1",
    label: "Parent 1",
    checked: false,
    children: [{
        id: "child-tr-1-1",
        label: "Child 1_1",
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: "child-tr-1-1-1",
            label: "Child 1_1_1",
            checked: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "child-tr-1-1-2",
            label: "Child 1_1_2",
            checked: false,
            children: [],
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "child-tr-1-2",
        label: "Child 1_2",
        checked: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "parent-tr-2",
    label: "Parent 2",
    checked: false,
    children: [{
        id: "child-tr-2-1",
        label: "Child 2_1",
        checked: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: "child-tr-2-2",
        label: "Child 2_2",
        checked: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: "child-tr-2-3",
        label: "Child 2_3",
        checked: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ]
  },
]

const getRowsFlat = (data) => data.reduce((a, c) => [...a, c, ...getRowsFlat(c.children)], [])

const setChecked = (id, data, checkedState) => {
  data.forEach(e => {
    // setting children checked if parent is clicked
    if (e.id === id || id === "parent-force") {
      e.checked = checkedState ?? !e.checked
      if (e.id === id) {
        setChecked("parent-force", e.children, e.checked)
      } else {
        setChecked("parent-force", e.children)
      }
    } else {
      setChecked(id, e.children)
    }

    // if ANY of the children is set to checked, parent should be checked
    if (e.children.length && e.children.some(({
        checked
      }) => checked)) {
      e.checked = true
    }

    // if NONE of the children is set to checked, parent should not be checked
    if (e.children.length && e.children.every(({
        checked
      }) => !checked)) {
      e.checked = false
    }
  })
}

// row HTML template
const getRowHtml = (data) => {
  return `
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="${data.id}" ${ data.checked ? "checked" : null }/>
        <label for="${data.id}">${data.label}</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  `
}

// table update function
const updateContainer = (container) => (data) => {
  container.innerHTML = data.map(getRowHtml).join("")
}

// initialization
const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody")
const updateTableBody = updateContainer(tbody)
// first render
setChecked(null, data) // if run with id NULL, then only the children can affect the parent
updateTableBody(getRowsFlat(data))

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#table").on("click", "input", function() {
    const thisId = $(this).attr("id")
    setChecked(thisId, data)
    updateTableBody(getRowsFlat(data))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Dear this is the thing which i want make but your code rendered data by api or something else but in my case i have html table.  Would you like to explain it with html row data because i don't understand how to build this table using html table i don't `API` data so please explain it with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same id multiple times.

Check following code with class instead of id:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <!-- parent -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" class="subject1" />Parent
      </td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- child -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" class="ticker1" />Child</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" class="ticker1" />Child</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" class="ticker1" />Child</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- parent -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" class="subject2" />Parent
      </td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- child -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" class="ticker2" />Child</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" class="ticker2" />Child</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" class="ticker2" />Child</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ticker1").click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".subject1").prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        $(".subject1").prop("checked", false);
      }
    });
    $(".ticker2").click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".subject2").prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        $(".subject2").prop("checked", false);
      }
    });
    
  });
</script>
```

Here I modified the code by changing ids to classes and made other necessary changes.